# Which version of Jackson is Google App Engine 1.8.6 repackaging?

Tags: google-app-engine, jackson, google-cloud-endpoints

Firstly, I'd like to know how to find this out for myself next time.  If not, then can somebody tell me?

The reason I want to know is because I want to use the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation on my Cloud Endpoints entities to deal with recursive serialization, but it doesn't compile.  I guess this would mean it's some Jackson version less than 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use repackaged libs - they are for internal GAE use only. They are not part of official API and can change at any time.

Include your own Jackson jar in your project.

Comment: Am I the one "using" the JAR?  It's something internal to GAE (Jackson) that's consuming the annotations in the Entity classes that I must define, so it seems relevant to know which annotations are supported.  If I pull in my own Jackson JAR, I don't think that will have any effect on GAE's parsing of my Entity class.  Will it?

Answer (score 0):

Like Peter says, include your own Jackson jar.  Make your code use this Jackson library.  GAE will use their repackaged JSON parser or whatever they change it to (even not necessarily Jackson).  That is of no concern to your project.  GAE has no reason to look for Jackson annotations on your Entity classes - only your source code should tell only your Jackson jar to do that.